# SSO implementation to integrate Jasper Server with my existing application

Tags: web-applications, spring-security, single-sign-on, jasperserver

I know this question has been asked many times but I haven't been able to find an acceptable solution. I am using Jasper Server 5.0.1 and know that I can implement SSO using LDAP, CAS, SiteMinder, JAAS, etc.

My existing web application is based on Spring Security (Acegi) as is the case for Jasper Server and would prefer to somehow utilize the same. I have already done a POC on a custom Token-based solution based on method inbuilt in later versions of the server using [this link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-authentication-cookbook/v56/token-based-authentication).

Is there any "cleaner" solution that I can use? Is it worth integrating an authentication service like CAS, JAAS, etc? I would like to retain my existing form-based login implementation where user details are stored in my MSSQL Database? If yes, which authentication service should I choose? Would prefer something that is easy to integrate with minimum code / config changes as well as ease of use for the end user.

Lastly, just wanted to mention that I would be integrating Jasper Server to utilize its Adhoc Views feature via the iframe method.

Thanks everyone for all your help and advice.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't receive any answers so went with the Token-based approach itself.

Comment: Hey how did you implement token based approach?